# Do not resolve dependencies in dart 2.0 sample app project

Tags: dart, webstorm, dart-pub

1. Installed JetBrains WebStorm 2018.1 EAP
2. Installed Dart using a third-party installer by link from official site
3. Created a new project, with default settings. Dart version 2.0.0-dev.20.0. Check `Generate sample content` checkbox and select `Dart Web App`. `Create`.
4. Press `Run`.
5. Get message:

> No pubspec.lock file found, please run "pub get" first.

6. Press  'get dependences'. In the window below, I get the message:

> Working dir: C:\Users\Anton\Source\Front\untitled "C:\Program
>   Files\Dart\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat" get Resolving dependencies...
>   Overriding the upper bound Dart SDK constraint to <=2.0.0-dev.20.0 for
>   the following packages:
>
> browser
>
> To disable this you can set the PUB_ALLOW_PRERELEASE_SDK system
>   environment variable to `false`, or you can silence this message by
>   setting it to `quiet`.
>   + browser 0.10.0+2 Downloading browser 0.10.0+2... Process finished with exit code -1 073 741 795

7. I try to execute `pub get` through the terminal - and get the same message
8. I add environment variable `PUB_ALLOW_PRERELEASE_SDK`, like this: `set PUB_ALLOW_PRERELEASE_SDK=false`, but but after nothing has changed
9. I try download manually, but I can not find a description of where these files should be located, relative to the project

I'm new to the frontend and especially to dart so most likely I miss some small detail

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: untitled
version: 0.0.1
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  browser: any
dev_dependencies:
#  unittest: any
```

**untitled.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="untitled.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sample_container_id">
      <p id="sample_text_id">Click me!</p>
    </div>
    <script type="application/dart" src="untitled.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a problem. You can ignore the message. It's only a hint that during the transition phase until a Dart 2.0.0 release is available dependency resolution works a bit different than "normally". You should get a `pubspec.lock` file with the resolved dependencies and a `.packages` file with the paths to the locations where the packages where downloaded to.

Answer (score 0):

As [Gunter said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672654/do-not-resolve-dependencies-in-dart-2-0-sample-app-project#comment84343829_48672654), the warning about `PUB_ALLOW_PRERELEASE_SDK` is to be expected while using a pre-release Dart SDK.